# React/Redux/Typescript - Material-UI errors with TS322, when using a nested list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

I have created a small repo of the issue I'm experiencing [here](https://github.com/piriej/ReactReduxJSSTypescript). I am starting to question the wisdom of using typescript in this instance.

My tech stack is as follows: a Typescript React/Redux project, created using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). I am using [React Material UI](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#typescript).

However, When using the simple [Nested List sample](https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/) ( [See here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/lists/NestedList.js) ), within the provided [typescript sample](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/create-react-app-with-typescript),  I seem to hit up against, what appears to be the following Typing issue:

[image: Error TS322]

> Type error: Type '{ children: string; component: string; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListItemTextProps & {
>   children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'component' does not exist on
>   type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListItemTextProps & { children?:
>   ReactNode; }'.  TS2322

If this is genuinely a typing issue, it isn't immediately clear to me which project to raise the issue against (@types/material-ui?). Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Why do you think `component` is defined on `@material-ui/core/ListItemText`? https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-text/

Comment: Thanks. You are of course correct. Component is not defined on ListItemText, however I am under the (Mis?)belief It is complaining about component not being defined on [ListSubHeader](https://material-ui.com/api/list-subheader/)?

Comment: `import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";` --- you're importing `ListItemText`, then giving it a `ListSubheader`. `ListItemText` does not have that property, the name can be arbitrary and changes nothing.

Comment: ... oh, (Insert face palm here). Thank you @zerkms appreciate your help.